# Removing space in itemize environments

Tags: spacing, lists

I have a macro that has itemize environment in it.
I'm trying to remove the spaces between items, preceding, and following texts with control commands, but I still have spaces. How can I remove them? (How can I make tighter itemize environment?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
Function:%
\begin{itemize}%
#1%
\end{itemize} \topsep0pt \parskip0pt \partopsep0pt \itemsep0pt \parsep0pt
Data:%
\begin{itemize}%
#2%
\end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\fuda{%
\item A%
\item B}
{%
\item X%
\item Y
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itemize` sets its own spacing parameters at call time, so setting them before calling it is useless. You can do it easily with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\fuda}[2]{%
  Function:
  \begin{itemize}
  #1
  \end{itemize}
  Data:
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
  #2
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\fuda{
  \item A
  \item B
}{
  \item X
  \item Y
}
\end{document}
```

This is a place where almost no `%` is needed in the definition body, but they don't hurt, either.

[image]